# FIFO type of container - Which STL Container is most suitable and why?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I was recently tasked on implementing a buffer which will be used as a temporary storage by a logging class. The logging class itself is a singleton and the observer listener pattern is used. You can expect thousands of messages to be logged with this class.

Now the problem lies here :

We have a trace logging option which is used for deguging purposes. When this option is on, the count of messages/second is increased exponentially. In the release code trace logging is disabled, however a buffer which can store a fixed number of messages e.g. 10000 is dumped into the log **IF** an error occurs, so that the developers can identify the root of the problem.

If the buffer is full the oldest message is removed to free space for the newest message.

```
void Log::storeToBuffer(const LogType_E & type_in, const LogDomain_E & domain_in,const int & id_in, const char * msg_in)
{
    if(this->myEnableTraceBuffer)
    {
        if(static_cast<std::list<Message> * >(this->myRingBuffer)->size() < this->myRingBufferMaxSize)
        {
            static_cast<std::list<Message> * >(this->myRingBuffer)->push_back(Message(type_in, domain_in, id_in, msg_in));
        }
        else
        {
            //buffer full so remove oldest element and add new
            if(static_cast<std::list<Message> * >(this->myRingBuffer)->size() > 0) static_cast<std::list<Message> * >(this->myRingBuffer)->pop_front();
            static_cast<std::list<Message> * >(this->myRingBuffer)->push_back(Message(type_in, domain_in, id_in, msg_in));
        }
    }
}
```

I implemented this with std::list , very simply using push_back/pop_front to exploit the constant delete/insert execution time. (*don't ask for the void casting, not my decision*).

But since the buffer size is fixed, and not likely to be changed during the lifetime of an object, maybe vector with explicit index manipulation is more suitable? For example there can be two indeces , start/current starting both at position 0. When the vector is full and we add something start moves to position 1 and and current to position 0, thus when printing the result we have the right order.

Maybe another STL container is more suitable for this kind of thing?

Thank your for your patience to read this long wall of text. I am here to answer any questions.

Comment: This is actually FIFO and not FILO/LIFO.

Comment: @ChristianRau Yes you are absolutely right.

Comment: just curious, why do you keep the log in memory? if there is a crash your log is gone just when you need it the most.

Comment: @AndersK. We just keep the trace messages in memory, not the log itself. When you have millions of messages , it impacts performance severely, so trace messages are only used for degugging purposes.

Comment: true, thanks for the info and have a good one.

Comment: Slight quibble - why is `myRingBuffer` a pointer? If it's really *your* ring buffer, not shared with anyone else, then why not just use a collection object? OK, so in the case where you haven't enabled it then an empty collection is larger than a pointer, but not much larger. And probably a related question, what type are you casting that pointer from?

Comment: @SteveJessop It is a void *. The reason : The .h file cannot contain stl libraries to avoid implementation differences from various compilers. The .cpp file is however another story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ever heard of [`std::deque`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/)? :)
It allows amortized constant time random access and constant time push/pop operations on both sides. As such, it can be easily used as a FIFO queue.

That said, since it can be used as such so easily, there is a container adaptor [`std::queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/queue/), though it doesn't offer random access and an iterator interface.

Comment: Yes I considered this option. Is this any different than the current std::list implementation? Will I see any performance gain?

Comment: @FailedDev, `std::list` keeps a pair of link pointers for each element. If those pointers are large in relation to the item you're storing it can have an impact. `std::deque` also allows efficient random access but it doesn't seem that it's a requirement for your usage.

Comment: oh yes, very much so.  `std::deque` is effectively an unrolled `std::list`

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes I do not need random access at all.

Comment: It (`std::queue`) doesn't only offer no random access, but also no iteration, I think, which might be needed for the output logic. Of course you can just continuously pop, but this destroys the container.

Comment: @Chris: Right, I always forget just how bad the container adaptors actually are in terms of usability... edited.

Answer (score 3):

The `std::deque` can efficiently insert or delete at either the beginning or the end, making it an excellent structure for a buffer. It can be used as the template type for `std::queue` which would be perfect for your application - just check the size of the queue each time you do a `push`, and `pop` if the size is over the maximum.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst the std::list's push_back/pop_front are constant time, they will use heap allocation, which is likely to be your bottleneck here.

The approach you describe with std::vector will eliminate the heap allocation, and likely go faster as a result.
Using std::vector as you described is a circular buffer, and if you can use boost then there's a stl compliant one available here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html

Comment: Thanks for the time spent. Unfortunately I cannot use boost in this project.

Comment: That's a pity - I think std::deque will still end up doing a lot of allocating new chunks and free'ing old ones, even though you'll get better memory locality since it'll be allocated in chunks and won't be maintaining forward/back pointers all the time.

If performance is really really important to you, implementing a circular buffer with a vector as you described may be the way to go. However, depending on your malloc() implementation and other allocations going on in the app, the benefit may be very marginal.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a double ended queue, where elements can be added removed from the front/back and the C++ standard library's version of this is `std::deque`. It is similar to a `std::vector` in its functionality (e.g. access by index, but beware, no guaranteed continous storage) but supports fast insertion and deletion at the front and back. I think internally it is actually implemented as a plain array used like a ring buffer.

The only problem I see here is that it doesn't provide a `reserve` method, I think. So you cannot say from the beginning that it should make room for your potential 10000 elements and have to take some reallocations into account. But these should amortize, like for vectors. Still better than `std::list`'s 10000 or more small allocations. Once it has its size of 10000 elements there shouldn't be any allocations anymore, whereas a `std::list` would constantly deallocate and allocate new objects.

Actually you can also use `std::queue`, which by default uses `std::deque` as its underlying container type and only provides the few functions neccessary for a FIFO queue. But in this case you won't be able to access individual elements or iterate over all elements, which might be needed for your output logic.